# Longest Plateau Solution: the length and location of the longest continuous sequence of equal values

Tags: java

Here is a full program description with test cases and below it is my solution:

Given an array of integers int A[], find the length and location of the longest contiguous sequence of equal values for which the values of the elements just before and just after this sequence are smaller.

You should just print these two numbers (first is the length and second is the starting index of the plateau).

To complete the definition, we can consider there are imaginary index positions at A[-1] and A[A.length] where A[-1] < A[0] and A[A.length] < A[A.length-1]. Therefore, the plateau can start/end at both ends of array A. This condition guarantees the existence of a plateau. A plateau can be of length 1.

**Example 1:**

```
java LongestPlateau 1 2 2 2 2 1
```

With these command-line arguments, the program should print:

```
4
1
```

**Example 2:**

```
java LongestPlateau 1 2 2 2 2 3
```

With these command-line arguments, the program should print:

```
1
5
```

**Example 3:**

```
java LongestPlateau 3 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 0 1 1 1 1 0
```

With these command-line arguments, the program should print:

```
4
12
```

**Here is my Solution:**

```
public class LongestPlateau {
private static int[] parseInputArray(String[] args) {
    int[] value = new int[args.length+1];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < args.length; i++){
        if (i == args.length-1) value[i] = 0; // this imaginary last value of the array ensures that if the plateau is the last value of the array, then it outputs the correct answer
        value[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }
    return value;
}
public static void printLargestPlateau(int[] values) {
    int biggestStartIndex = -1;
    int biggestLength = 0;
    int currentIndex = 1;
    int currentPlateauStartIndex = 1;
    int currentLength = 1;
    boolean plateauStarted = false;
    while (currentIndex < values.length) {
        if(isStartOfPlateau(currentIndex, values)){
            currentLength = 1;
            plateauStarted = true;
            currentPlateauStartIndex = currentIndex;
        } else if (isEndOfPlateau(currentIndex, values)) {
            if(plateauStarted && currentLength > biggestLength){
                biggestLength = currentLength;
                biggestStartIndex = currentPlateauStartIndex;
            }
            plateauStarted = false;
            currentLength = 1;
        } else {
            currentLength++;
        }
        currentIndex++;
    }
    System.out.println(biggestLength +"\n"+biggestStartIndex);
}

private static boolean isStartOfPlateau(int index, int[] values){
    if(index <= 0){
        return false;
    }
    return values[index-1] < values[index];
}

private static boolean isEndOfPlateau(int index, int[] values){
    if(index <= 0){
        return false;
    }
    return values[index - 1] > values[index];
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] values = parseInputArray(args);
    printLargestPlateau(values);
}
}
```

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't see a question in your "question". Did I miss it?

Comment: I was looking for a solution to this question all over the place but could not find the ideal and correct one. Then I wrote my own solution and it tested correctly. So I thought it is worth posting it here, in case someone in the future faces the same situation.

Comment: So [edit] your question and make it a "question" and then post an [answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: This code does not detect platoes starting at the first index and ending at the last index of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, existing code fails to detect plateaus at the start and the end of the input data, and the following implementation fixes this issue.

```java
static void printLargestPlateau(int ... arr) {
    int start = -1, maxStart = -1;
    int length = 0, maxLength = -1;
    boolean onPlateau = false;
    
    if (arr.length > 0) {
        start = 0;
        length = 1;
        onPlateau = true;
        
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {
                if (onPlateau) {
                    length++;
                }
            } else if (arr[i] < arr[i - 1]) {
                if (length > maxLength) {
                    maxLength = length;
                    maxStart = start;
                }
                onPlateau = false;
            } else { // possible start of new plateau
                onPlateau = true;
                start = i;
                length = 1;
            }
        }
        // check possible plateau at the end
        if (length > maxLength) {
            maxLength = length;
            maxStart = start;                
        }
    }
    System.out.println(maxLength);
    System.out.println(maxStart);
}
```

Tests:

```java
int[][] tests = {
    {},
    {1},
    {1, 1},
    {1, 2},
    {1, 1, 2},
    {1, 2, 2},
    {1, 2, 1},
    {1, 2, 3},
    {1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1},
    {1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3},
    {3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
    {3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}
};
for (int[] arr : tests) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    printLargestPlateau(arr);
    System.out.println("-".repeat(arr.length * 3));
}
```

Output:

```
[]
-1
-1

[1]
1
0
---
[1, 1]
2
0
------
[1, 2]
1
1
------
[1, 1, 2]
1
2
---------
[1, 2, 2]
2
1
---------
[1, 2, 1]
1
1
---------
[1, 2, 3]
1
2
---------
[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
2
4
------------------------------
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
4
1
------------------
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
1
5
------------------
[3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
4
12
---------------------------------------------------
[3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
6
7
---------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, it gives you the location and size of each plateau. I hope it helps:

```
public class LongestPlateau {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 3, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 10, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10};
    int count;
    int j = 2;

    for (int i = 1; i < a.length - 1; i++, j++) {
        count = 0;
        if(a[i-1]<a[i]) {  
            while (j < a.length && (a[i] == a[j])) {
                count++;
                if (a[i+2]<a[i+1]) System.out.println("location is "+ (j-count) + " size is "+ (count+1));
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }
     }
```