# Longest plateau in array. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write an algorithm to find the longest plateau in a array, if there are multiple, it should return the plateau with the lowest start index. If there are none, it should return -1 as start and 0 as length. I think I have solved it, but my code is still failing some tests.

A "plateau"  is a stretch of equal values that is surrounded by lower values or at the edges of the array.

Data input:
1
2
3
3
2
1
2
3
3
2

Data output: 2 2

Hope you have any ideas!

I don't know why I fail these test, it just says failed (yes it's an assignment), but I feel like I stumbling around blind, trying to debug working code.

```
private int[] findPlateau(int[] array){
    int[] result = new int[2];

    int currentStartVal = 0;
    int currentStart = -1;
    int currentLength = 0;

    int maxStart = -1;
    int maxLength = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i]==currentStartVal){
            //Increase length
            currentLength++;
            currentStartVal = array[i];
        }
        else if(array[i]>currentStartVal){
            //Start new length
            currentStart = i;
            currentLength = 1;
            currentStartVal = array[i];
        }
        else if(array[i]<currentStartVal){
            //End of length
            if (currentLength > maxLength){
                maxStart = currentStart;
                maxLength = currentLength;
            }
            else if(currentLength == maxLength){
                if(maxStart>currentStart){
                    maxStart = currentStart;
                }
            }
            currentStart = -1;
            currentStartVal = array[i];
            currentLength = -1;
        }



    }

    if (currentLength > maxLength) {
        result[1] = currentLength;
        result[0] = currentStart;
        maxStart = currentStart;
        maxLength = currentLength;
    }


    if(maxStart == -1 || maxLength <= 1){
        result[0] = -1;
        result[1] = 0;
    }else{
        result[0] = maxStart;
        result[1] = maxLength;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should show your data, current output and expected output.  And keep it short.

Comment: You say it's failing the tests, but I don't see any tests. I don't know what you are asking us to help with

Comment: are zeros allowed in the array? (probably will fail if array is just zeros) If the specification is *"location of the longest contiguous sequence of equal values where the values of the elements just before and just after this sequence are smaller"* it will also fail since it also considers an eventual plateau at the very start or end of the array

Comment: The array [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] should return (1, 3), but doesn't. If you append a [2] at the end, it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Longest Plateau Solution: the length and location of the longest continuous sequence of equal values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65977194/longest-plateau-solution-the-length-and-location-of-the-longest-continuous-sequ)

Answer (score 1):

There's a few items you aren't doing that helps you solve problems like this.

- You aren't properly initializing your values.  Yes, you assign them something, but that something isn't related to the input.  For example, an array starting with a `0` value will use different logic blocks than one starting with a `1` value, even though both of the logic blocks will do the same operations, by different logic.

To fix a problem like this

```
currentStartVal = array[0];
currentLength = 0;
```

makes the logic always extend the plateau for the first element, extending it to a length of 1.

Comment: Hm. I think that a "plateau" here isn't just a stretch of equal values, but a stretch of equal values that is surrounded by lower values or at the edges of the array, so the distinction between greater than and less than is useful.

Comment: @MOehm You may be right, if the OP can chime in that would help

Comment: Yep, a "plateau"  is a stretch of equal values that is surrounded by lower values or at the edges of the array

Comment: @Joha6210 That explains the need for testing both greater than and less than.  I'lm going to trim my answer